# IOS and TableView: detail view is not killed when back to table

Tags: ios

I have got an ios project with `NavigationViewController`, `TableVC` and `DetailVC`.
In my detail view controller i have got a video. If the app starts playing the video and i go back to the `tableVC` the sound still can be heard and notes in consul from detail view are adding. I can't use `viewDidDisappear` function to stop the video because it's called when the video is getting full screen too. 
I also use `SWRevealViewController` in my app to display slide out menu. 
ARC is turned on.
Please, help me.

Comment: First of all excuse my poor english, but can't you just override the "goBack" method and call the stop function from MPMoviePlayerController? Hope it helps

Comment: I can override viewDidDisappear method, but as i mentioned above - that is not the case. If you know what the method is called when user taps "back" button of navigation controller, o swipe back - tell me and I will be grateful.

Comment: I dont know the exact method, but you can override the button as well. I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the button and make it call whatever method you want:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                         target:self
                         action:@selector(myMethod)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but that is not what i want. That button is already set it's not the only way to leave the detail view - user can also swipe from left to get back.